# Scoll view hangs while loading images from url in ImageLoader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using Image Loader to display Image in my layout ,which I am creating dynamically inside horizontal scroll view. My custom Linear layout has 6 Image Tiles, which i manage by weight property inside linear layout. and adding this linear layout inside parent linear which has Horizontal scroll view as parent.

My scoll view has performance problem on imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap) inside image loader.
UI hangs on loading image inside imageview.

Comment: Do you use adapter ?

Comment: Search for Picasso. Easy Solution for this kinda problem.

Comment: No I am not using adapter, I am adding different views in loop inside horizontal scroll view. My views are changing on the basis of condition as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) as ImageLoader Library

it is a great and easy library 
.it's a sample on usage of it

```
 Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);
```

Comment: I also try it with  Picasso. But the same problem. I think my image layout problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to managing memory and have good performance with images in Android, especially with group of images 
in the list, it becomes a very difficult task, in your case it would be interesting to use the `TwoWayView`, if you still do not know or 
opted for it, the fact that you can use an `Adapter` with `ViewHolder` in `TwoWayView` helps a lot, he has the option of displaying the list in order 
`Horizontal` or `Vertical`.

[An AdapterView with support for vertical and horizontal scrolling](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)

[Vertical ListView having a Horizontal ListView](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView)